# how do you remember a checkbox in a cookie.

Tags: javascript, cookies

i want to know how to remember a check box value in a cookie i have method createCookie. 
this is the method:

```
 function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }
```

Comment: So get a method that is getCookie

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should read this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script)(it is a permalink to the script, but if you have time read it all, it is very good to understand how cookie work).

However this is the code to get a cookie value:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```